How can I launch a custom template splash screen when the program starts under MacOS?
I've been trying for a long time to get blender to launch my own "templates" at startup, with a custom "splash screen".
I tried adding my "splash.png" images to my "my_splash" folder along the path:
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.6/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system

But this doesn't give me the desired result. When I start Blender, the original start screen starts. But I can go to File > New > my_splash and then click Blender Logo > Splash Screen and it loads what I want (custom image).
I want to make it run automatically. How can I achieve this?
I've seen people do this on Windows. To do this, they create a new shortcut and in the properties, add the argument: --app -template my_splash. As a result, when the program starts, the required splash screen starts.
I tried to do something similar on MacOS by creating a Bash file with the following content:
open -n /Applications/Blender.app --args -template my_splash

When I try to launch it, the application starts to load, but immediately closes (without having time to open)
What should I do? Is it possible to implement this somehow on MacOS?
I have Blender 3.6.9 MacOS 12.7.4

Yes, I was able to do it!
I will leave the solution for those who will encounter this problem in the future.
You need to enter the following command in the terminal:
open -n /Applications/Blender.app --args --app-template my_splash

Instead of "my_splash" you should specify the name of your "template"
My mistake was that I may have used outdated information. Previously, it was enough to use the "-template" command after "--args". Now, you need to use "--app-template".
Information was taken from here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#misc-options
(use your version of blender)
